# ID collision with Graphene-SQLAlchemy Interface class plus Node Interface

Tags: sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I've written Graphene models for polymorphic entities represented in my database w/SQLalchemy.

The problem is simple:

I want to create an interface that reflects my SQLAlchemy models for Graphene but also either a) implements Node or b) does not conflict with Node and allows me to retrieve the model's ID without needing to add ... on Node {id} to the query string.

have to exclude the ID field from my ORM-based interface or field conflicts with the Node interface, by doing so in order to get the ID then you need to add ...on Node { id }, which is ugly.

I created an SQLAlchemyInterface object that extends graphene.Interface. Many (but not all) of my models used this as well as Node as interfaces.  The first problem was that this contains an ID field and it conflicted with the Node interface.

I excluded the id field to not interfere with Node, but then found I could not directly query ID on my models anymore, and had to add ... on Node {id} to the query string.

I then decided to have this SQLAlchemyInterface extend Node.  I don't love this approach because I need to use another (named) Node interface for all of my models that don't necessarily need to implement SQLAlchemyInterface

```py
class SQLAlchemyInterface(Node):
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass_with_meta__(
            cls,
            model=None,
            registry=None,
            only_fields=(),
            exclude_fields=(),
            connection_field_factory=default_connection_field_factory,
            _meta=None,
            **options
    ):
        _meta = SQLAlchemyInterfaceOptions(cls)
        _meta.name = f'{cls.__name__}Node'

        autoexclude_columns = exclude_autogenerated_sqla_columns(model=model)
        exclude_fields += autoexclude_columns

        assert is_mapped_class(model), (
            "You need to pass a valid SQLAlchemy Model in " '{}.Meta, received "{}".'
        ).format(cls.__name__, model)

        if not registry:
            registry = get_global_registry()

        assert isinstance(registry, Registry), (
            "The attribute registry in {} needs to be an instance of "
            'Registry, received "{}".'
        ).format(cls.__name__, registry)

        sqla_fields = yank_fields_from_attrs(
            construct_fields(
                model=model,
                registry=registry,
                only_fields=only_fields,
                exclude_fields=exclude_fields,
                connection_field_factory=connection_field_factory
            ),
            _as=Field
        )
        if not _meta:
            _meta = SQLAlchemyInterfaceOptions(cls)
        _meta.model = model
        _meta.registry = registry
        connection = Connection.create_type(
            "{}Connection".format(cls.__name__), node=cls)
        assert issubclass(connection, Connection), (
            "The connection must be a Connection. Received {}"
        ).format(connection.__name__)
        _meta.connection = connection
        if _meta.fields:
            _meta.fields.update(sqla_fields)
        else:
            _meta.fields = sqla_fields
        super(SQLAlchemyInterface, cls).__init_subclass_with_meta__(_meta=_meta, **options)

    @classmethod
    def Field(cls, *args, **kwargs):  # noqa: N802
        return NodeField(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def node_resolver(cls, only_type, root, info, id):
        return cls.get_node_from_global_id(info, id, only_type=only_type)

    @classmethod
    def get_node_from_global_id(cls, info, global_id, only_type=None):
        try:
            node: DeclarativeMeta = one_or_none(session=info.context.get('session'), model=cls._meta.model, id=global_id)
            return node
        except Exception:
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def from_global_id(global_id):
        return global_id

    @staticmethod
    def to_global_id(type, id):
        return id
```

Interface impls, Models + Query code examples:

```py
class CustomNode(Node):
    class Meta:
        name = 'UuidNode'

    @staticmethod
    def to_global_id(type, id):
        return '{}:{}'.format(type, id)

    @staticmethod
    def get_node_from_global_id(info, global_id, only_type=None):
        type, id = global_id.split(':')
        if only_type:
            # We assure that the node type that we want to retrieve
            # is the same that was indicated in the field type
            assert type == only_type._meta.name, 'Received not compatible node.'

        if type == 'User':
            return one_or_none(session=info.context.get('session'), model=User, id=global_id)
        elif type == 'Well':
            return one_or_none(session=info.context.get('session'), model=Well, id=global_id)


class ControlledVocabulary(SQLAlchemyInterface):
    class Meta:
        name = 'ControlledVocabularyNode'
        model = BaseControlledVocabulary


class TrackedEntity(SQLAlchemyInterface):
    class Meta:
        name = 'TrackedEntityNode'
        model = TrackedEntityModel

class Request(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    """Request node."""

    class Meta:
        model = RequestModel
        interfaces = (TrackedEntity,)

class User(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    """User Node"""

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        interfaces = (CustomNode,)

class CvFormFieldValueType(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = CvFormFieldValueTypeModel
        interfaces = (ControlledVocabulary,)


common_field_kwargs = {'id': graphene.UUID(required=False), 'label': graphene.String(required=False)}

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    """Query objects for GraphQL API."""

    node = CustomNode.Field()
    te_node = TrackedEntity.Field()
    cv_node = ControlledVocabulary.Field()

    # Non-Tracked Entities:
    users: List[User] = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(User)
    # Generic Query for any Tracked Entity:
    tracked_entities: List[TrackedEntity] = FilteredConnectionField(TrackedEntity, sort=None, filter=graphene.Argument(TrackedEntityInput))
    # Generic Query for any Controlled Vocabulary:
    cv: ControlledVocabulary = graphene.Field(ControlledVocabulary, controlled_vocabulary_type_id=graphene.UUID(required=False),
                                              base_entry_key=graphene.String(required=False),
                                              **common_field_kwargs)
    cvs: List[ControlledVocabulary] = FilteredConnectionField(ControlledVocabulary, sort=None, filter=graphene.Argument(CvInput))

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_with_filters(info: ResolveInfo, model: Type[SQLAlchemyObjectType], **kwargs):
        query = model.get_query(info)
        log.debug(kwargs)
        for filter_name, filter_value in kwargs.items():
            model_filter_column = getattr(model._meta.model, filter_name, None)
            log.debug(type(filter_value))
            if not model_filter_column:
                continue
            if isinstance(filter_value, SQLAlchemyInputObjectType):
                log.debug(True)
                filter_model = filter_value.sqla_model
                q = FilteredConnectionField.get_query(filter_model, info, sort=None, **kwargs)
                # noinspection PyArgumentList
                query = query.filter(model_filter_column == q.filter_by(**filter_value))
                log.info(query)
            else:
                query = query.filter(model_filter_column == filter_value)
        return query

    def resolve_tracked_entity(self, info: ResolveInfo, **kwargs):
        entity: TrackedEntity = Query.resolve_with_filters(info=info, model=BaseTrackedEntity, **kwargs).one()
        return entity

    def resolve_tracked_entities(self, info, **kwargs):
        query = Query.resolve_with_filters(info=info, model=BaseTrackedEntity, **kwargs)
        tes: List[BaseTrackedEntity] = query.all()
        return tes

    def resolve_cv(self, info, **kwargs):
        cv: List[BaseControlledVocabulary] = Query.resolve_with_filters(info=info, model=BaseControlledVocabulary, **kwargs).one()
        log.info(cv)
        return cv

    def resolve_cvs(self, info, **kwargs):
        cv: List[BaseControlledVocabulary] = Query.resolve_with_filters(info=info, model=BaseControlledVocabulary, **kwargs).all()
        return cv
```

schema:

```py
schema = Schema(query=Query, types=[*tracked_members, *cv_members])
```

I would like to be able to not extend Node with SQLAlchemyInterface and rather add Node back to the list of interfaces for TrackedEntity and ControlledVocabulary but be able to perform a query like this:

```
query queryTracked {
      trackedEntities{
            id
            (other fields)
            ... on Request {
                    (request specific fields)
             }
       }
```